# FormsAuthentication authCookie is null only for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am experiencing a strange problem with asp.net forms authentication.  This problem only occurs for 3 users out of 30+ users that have successfully logged in.  I am using very basic auth code that I have used many times and have never seen this problem.  After the users successfully authenticates and the auth cookie is created, cookie added, and response.redirect to FormsAuthentication.GetRedirect(userid, false) is called.  The Application_AuthenticateRequest method in Global.asax is hit.

```
// Extract the forms authentication cookie
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if (null == authCookie)
        {
            // There is no authentication cookie.
            return;
        }
```

So immediately after a "good" cookie is saved and the redirect occurs the cookie is null.  I have run the code through the debugger and the cookie is only null on these 3 users.  But the cookie looks the same as the cookie for the many users that login successfully.

Any ideas?  This is standard code that should just work.

Comment: Try reproducing the problem with Fiddler and see if auth cookie is set.

Comment: Are there any settings on the user computers that could potentially block any cookies from being created?

Comment: From the same computer, mbalkema could log in successfully as himself, yet as one of these three users, the cookie was not successfully set. It is not an issue of their computer so much as something weird happening in the FormsAuthentication module

Comment: As Anthony said, it may be a clientside issue for some users' PCs. Can the users in question log in on another PC to compare results? Perhaps get them to try 2 different Browsers (IE + FF, etc.) to compare there as well. Lastly temporarily set all security settings in browser related to privacy and cookies to lowest setting and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the response.  The problem does not seem to be a browser issue.  I see the same results logging in with the users in question credentials and running the website locally thru the debugger in IE and FF.  This morning I had the user login using someone who can login's pc...to no avail.

Comment: @KevinP - he was able to duplicate the issue on his PC. Logged in as "Brad" and  as himself, from the same computer. We watched the cookie being set in the debugger and then not being there on the next page request, but ONLY for Brads user. Everything went through the same process, Brad auths correctly, the cookie is set but when it came to the next page request and the Cookie came back null. With the same code, mbalkema's cookie was set. It's not a client PC issue as it's dupicated from the same PC, only difference was the user who was logged in. Brad has the same permissions as mbalkema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the "good" cookie is saved and exits to the response? It is possible in FormsAuthentication for a good cookie to be added to the header but the response is killed on the way out by some other system error (w3wp.exe crashing for instance) so a new response is generated without the cookie and the redirect occurs anyway.

In my own experience with a problem similar to this, I had a custom Principal class that was crashing after authentication (and cookie creation) and instead of writing an appropriate cookie, removed the cookie from the response entirely.

Comment: Thanks Joel for your answer.  I was not exactly like your problem, but your advice to check the cookie after being added to the response but before the redirect and authCookie = null check in Global.asax  turned out to be super helpful.  As it turned out either the length of the AD groups string or a character in the AD Group string was corrupting the cookie.  I wasn't using the groups from AD so I just stopped getting them after authentication.  Everything is working now.  Thanks again.